# How to change the color of the iOS push notification in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

How can I change the color of the iOS push notification from the default blue to any other desired color in Xcode using `Objective-C`?

Comment: Five years later... Any changes about this?

Comment: 7 years later, and still nothing seems like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot change the color of push notification. Apple has not provided such kind of support.

Comment: Any links to the documentation would be helpful for reference